# Delete the decimal after comma

Tags: php

I want delete all the numbers after a comma or replace the point `.` by comma `,` 
I did these functions but doesn't work:

```
public static function millionFormat($number){
    $newNumber=round(($number/1000000),0).' billion'; //;   round(($n/1000000000),1).' billion';
    $newNumber= number_format($newNumber,2,'.','');
    return $newNumber;
    }

public static function kiloFormat($number){
    $newNumber=round_up(($number/1000),0).' billion';
    $newNumber= number_format($newNumber,2,'.','');
    return $newNumber;
    }
}
```

How I can do it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and output?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)? It can do what you need, assuming you don't tell it to do something else (as you do know).

Comment: Input: 35013,79 and in output I find  24147.44137  (I devise the Input by 1,45)

Answer (score 0):

`string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )`

So:

`$newnumber = number_format(round(($number/1000000),0), 0, "", " ") . " billion";`